# Flutter ClipRRect border radius not working on bottomNavigationBar

Tags: flutter, flutter-bottomnavigation, border-radius

I am trying to recreate a floating navigation bar from my swift app in flutter. For some reason, using the code below, there is still no `borderRadius` in th UI. I've tried changing colors, making the container transparent, and even using a container with `boxDecoration`. Nothing is adding a `borderRadius` to the UI. Are navigation bars not allowed to have a `borderRadius` in flutter? Here is my code:

```
class MyHome extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHome({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomeState createState() => _MyHomeState();
}

class _MyHomeState extends State<MyHome> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {

  late TabController _tabController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _tabController = TabController(length: 5, vsync: this);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _tabController.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: TabBarView(
        children: [
          HomeScreen(),
          HomeScreen(),
          HomeScreen(),
          HomeScreen(),
          HomeScreen()
        ],
        controller: _tabController
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: Container(
        color: Colors.transparent,
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
        child: ClipRRect(
          clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50.0),
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.transparent,
            child: TabBar(
                labelColor: Colors.teal[200],
                unselectedLabelColor: Colors.blueGrey,
                indicator: UnderlineTabIndicator(
                    borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.teal),
                    insets: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(50, 0, 50, 40)
                ),
                indicatorColor: Colors.teal,
                tabs: [
                  Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.home_outlined)),
                  Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.explore_outlined)),
                  Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.camera_alt_outlined)),
                  Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.movie_outlined)),
                  Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.person_outline))
                ],
                controller: _tabController),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: seems to be working with your code sample, change the container color to see the difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: description]

I tried with your code by changing the outermost Container's color to Colors.transparent and this is the outcome I got. Is this the outcome of floating navigation bar that you are expecting? Perhaps you need to change the Scaffold's backgroundColor to have a better view of the border radius.

Comment: That is exactly what I am expecting to see... I did try setting the color of the outermost to transparent before. After just now trying it again, I am seeing that there is something else under it. After setting all the containers backgrounds to transparent, I am thinking that maybe there is automatically a background in the TabBarView to show the selected screen. I updated my question to show ALL the code for the navigator.

Comment: try adding extendBody: true to your Scaffold